# Is it possible to have “on the fly” MAC spoofing with IPv6 for encryption/anonymization purposes?

Tags: networking, encryption, ipv6, mac-address, spoofing

I am in school for network security and advanced Cisco, and one of my classes this semester we picked up on IPv6 as part of the MS Server 70-741 Exam.

When reading through the textbook and noticing that an IPv6 address contains an interfaces’ MAC address. I already read the blog post written by Kronos in 2011 about how to enable privacy addressing in IPv6 however the question I want to ask is a bit different.

What I want to know is if you can spoof a MAC address “on the fly” and stay connected to the internet? My thought process is that if you could auto generate a new MAC at random intervals it would be near impossible to trace traffic back to a single user.

But then again, there isn’t a lot of information on this topic (that I understand), and I am still very early in my classes.

Comment: Please edit your question tp provide a link for this 2011 Kronos blog post you mention, “I already read the blog post written by Kronos in 2011 about how to enable privacy addressing in IPv6.”

Comment: If you do know what a MAC address is and where it's used it's unclear why you expect it to impact the "traceability" of traffic.